# what is the name of such invocation "variable.methodName(data);" ?

Tags: java, instance-variables, method-invocation

```
public class Cat {
    private Cat variable;
    private int data;

    public void methodName(int data) {
        variable.methodName(data); //I am curious about this line
    }
}
```

> Can somebody tells me what is the name of such an invocation of a method
>   on an instance variable or why is this possible?
>   Sorry for all mistakes it's my first question.

Comment: non static method invocation

Comment: Delegation.....